# Proper way to implement Pikaday in Meteor React

Tags: meteor, reactjs, pikaday

I'm trying to implement Pikaday in Meteor React. I've searched through numerous solutions and I can't get any of them to work.  As I understand it, this is supposed to work:

I installed pikaday as follows: npm install -- save react react-pikaday.

Below is my code - What am I doing wrong?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Pikaday from 'react-pikaday';


export default class TestForm extends Component {

  ComponentDidMount() {

    new Pikaday({
      field: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.TestForm),
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      firstDay: 0,
      minDate: new Date(new Date()),
      maxDate: new Date('2050-12-31'),
      yearRange: [2000,2050],
    });
  }

  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field col s6">
              <input ref="TestForm" type="text"  />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form> 
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [github page](https://github.com/thomasboyt/react-pikaday), there is a component that can be used:

```
<Pikaday value={date} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

If you want to do the componentDidMount way, add an id to the div tag. and use `document.getElementById('textId');` instead of using ReactDOM.

I also noticed a typo in `ComponentDidMount() {`. It should be componentDidMount (c - lowercase).

Comment: Thanks @vijayst, it looks like the typo was the problem. It works like a charm now.